# How to safely associate data to factory array while still seeing automatic updates from factory in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, clone

Lets say I have an angular factory responsible for loading all Foos from the backend, and intermittently polls and updates foos.  Everyone uses my FooFactory to reference Foo objects so they get updates when foo data changes.

In one directive I would like to associate some information with a foo object, lets say sorting information for what order someone wishes to list some child element of foo in a table.

At first glance it would be easy to set foo.sort="blah" on each foo object to store this data.  However, this would change the foo objects shared by everyone, if someone in some other directive also did the same thing to store their table sorting data we would keep changing the others data, not good.

I could instead clone the foo object, then add my sort to the cloned object.  However, now my foo is different then the one in the FooFactory.  If FooFactory polls my backend and gets updated data my cloned foo will not see it, this is bad for me.

I could of course either keep a separate map of Foo objects to sort data, or some use of broadcast to keep my cloned foo objects up to date with fooFactory.  This works, but takes some small effort to implement every where I want to associate data.

I'm wondering if angular already has a more convenient means of doing this.  Is there some syntax that will allow me to 'clone' an object, so that data I add to the clone will not affect the original object, but still ensure the object is automatically updated when the original 'cloned' object is?  basically to Alias all the existing data of an object but ensure new data appended to it is only appended to my copy of the object?

Comment: i'm thinking about setting the original object as `.prototype`. `var a ={}; a.prototype = obj`

Comment: Angular doesn't have anything to offer. The case you're talking about fits [immutable pattern](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&q=immutable&ref=opensearch&s=stars&type=Repositories). But may also designate improper design that could be otherwise solvable by regular OOP practices. Some code would be much more helpful than its verbose description.

Comment: @JossefHarush `prototype` doesn't work like that. `setPrototypeOf` does.

Comment: thanks @estus :) just wanted to mention this feature in js * flies away *